# Fonts in Html local file

Tags: css

I have a problem when I choose a font in a CSS file. The font doesn't appear correctly in local HTML code.

```
#main_menu ul li
  {
      border-left:1px solid #dad8d8;
      font-family:"arabic transparent";
      font-size:16px;
      padding: 0px 20px;
      color: #e2001a;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
```

The font in the HTML file isn't like in the Photoshop design.

Comment: Did you include the font in your HTML/CSS file ?

Comment: Note that some fontnames are case sensitive

Comment: Not enough information. Do you mean that the font has been installed locally in the system and that it is used on the page but it looks different from the rendering in Photoshop? Then the answer is simply that web browsers render fonts differently from each other and from Photoshop. If there is something special in the rendering, there might be some way to reduce differences, but this would require detailed information about the differences and about the font (and some actual sample text).

Comment: Do you mean that the font has been installed locally in the system and that it is used on the page but it looks different from the rendering in Photoshop? 
that's right
the font in html local page not look like the font in photoshop

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just use any font on the web/in HTML. You have something called web-safe fonts and can add custom ones manual.

Check FontSquirrel for conversion techniques: http://www.fontsquirrel.com

If a font is on your local machine, it "can" work if the browser tries to look for it, but you can't rely on it as most other users that visit your website won't have it on theirs, making the font fallback to Arial or an alike default font.

Font-squirrel will give you these formats (name is an example);

- arabic.eot
- arabic.svg
- arabic.ttf
- arabic.woff

With all these included all major browsers should be able to read your custom font with the `@font-face` property:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arabic transparent';
    src: url('arabic.eot');
    src: url('arabic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('arabic.woff') format('woff'),
         url('arabic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('arabic.svg#arabic_transparent') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#main_menu ul li {
    font-family: 'arabic transparent';
}
```

Comment: Did you do the FontSquirrel conversion (download( then? It's not as simple as just pasting this code into your source.

Answer (score 0):

You better use [@font-face](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp) from CSS3. Example from W3School:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url('Sansation_Light.ttf'),
        url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9+ */
}

div
{
    font-family:myFirstFont;
}
```

Comment: I used it but my question is why font in html local file not look like the font in photoshop

Comment: I guess this is not problem of CSS, but browser rendering... And this is something what you can't affect at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to embbed the font

Use the following website for font generation
[www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'YourFont';
    src: url('YourFont.eot');
    src: url('YourFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('YourFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('YourFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('YourFont.svg#YourFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I Used font face
but My problem in local html file
I Installed this font in system and used it in photoshop but when i choose it in css code it be not look like in photoshop

Comment: Font is reflected? Some fonts will not get the same effect seen in the photoshop. Or you can use google fonts(http://www.google.com/fonts/). It will work better... :)